# How to push / setup cloned github project

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-clone

I have cloned entire project like this

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/NecronomiconCoding/NecroBot "D:\74 pokemon go\Pokemon-Go-Rare-Hunter-Bot"
```

It has created the project folder and cloned everything

Now i want to convert this into my project and push it into github

But no matter what i do i can not achieve it

When i type `git status` i see the below output

[image]

So what commands do i need to convert this into a github project and push it into remote repository?

I can not fork since i have previously forked project and it does not let me fork until i remove what i have or rename it which i do not want

Or can i fork with a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fork it on github then clone your own repo.

If you have already forked you should branch it.

```
git checkout -b new-branch <COMMIT_ID>
```

Comment: i can not fork since i have already forked previous version and it doesnt fork until i delete or rename it. Can i fork with a new name?

Comment: had the same issue with pokemon maps you should create a branch in your existing fork

Comment: In your case the `<COMMIT_ID>` is `5a61462b56b1828437549632831e5e8f5beb4644`

Comment: ye this seems another solution but i still prefer composing a new repository rather than a branch

Comment: create an empty repo, use `git remote set-url origin <URL>` where `<URL>` is the link to your `.git` on github, then `git push`

Comment: to use your latest command i have to setup the cloned project somehow. that is my problem already.

Comment: I created a new [repo](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/test-something) without initializing it, then cloned the [NecroBot](https://github.com/NecronomiconCoding/NecroBot) to my local PC. Changed the remote url `git remote set-url origin <URL>` then `git push` worked fine.